Rstudio Server active and running but cannot access web browser
I had an issue with Rstudio Server and had to kill some sessions and restart.
Now when I run rstudio-server status I get the following:
local@tb-1:/etc/rstudio$ rstudio-server status
● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-10-14 00:43:28 UTC; 8min ago
    Process: 2340274 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2340275 (rserver)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 567977)
     Memory: 2.8M
        CPU: 7.603s
     CGroup: /system.slice/rstudio-server.service
             └─2340275 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver

Oct 14 00:43:28 tb-1 systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
Oct 14 00:43:28 tb-1 systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.

So it's active and running... but when I go to the web browser to log-in (http://website:8787) it does not load. However, if I go to a terminal, log in, and grab the IP address (hostname -I) and then type IPaddress:8787 into the browser, it loads.
I suspect this has something to do with port forwarding and maybe some process that needs to be killed...but I am not experienced enough with Unix to really know if this is true.
When I check my ports, I get this:
local@tb-1:/etc/rstudio$ sudo netstat -tuln
[sudo] password for local:
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 18.27.79.38:68          0.0.0.0:*

EDIT:
For whatever reason, it's working now. I don't know what I did. I guess I'll just leave this up.
